# WPF Binding List of Checkboxes where IsChecked binds to membership of list

Tags: wpf, xaml, checkbox, binding, member

So I have a list of all possible values, and a list of occurring values, that occurs only once. Like **[A, B, C, D, E] and [D, A],** each element of the second list must be a member of the first as well.

I want to create a listview with one row per possible value, where each row is a checkbox, binding the content to the name of the value and IsChecked to something like occuringValues.contains(possibleValue). In my example this would look like:

```
[x] A

[ ] B

[ ] C

[x] D

[ ] E
```

Checking or unchecking a checkbox should add or remove an element from the occurring values list.

I've tried a number of approaches without much luck, like:

Creating a INotifyPropertyChanged-implementing helper class with a string and a bool (for IsChecked) and an ObservableCollection gives me control over the changes in my class, but changes in the class does not trigger my set function for the ObservableCollection, otherwise I could have updated my **[D, A]** list there.

I could change my GUI to make things easier, listing the occuringValues and making a comboBox with possibleValues, but I'd prefer to use checkboxes, if you have an idea for me.

Comment: Where does the "occurs" list get used? Are you binding it to some kind of UI list control too? If so, do you want this list to update as items are checked/unchecked in the first list?

Comment: The occurs list only present itself in this checkbox list, it is not used anywhere else in the gui but it is connected to a database, so the user must be able to check a box, click save and have the added element in the database. I could read it manually at savetime of course, but I'd prefer to add it declaratively in a nice mvvm way instead of doing it imperatively/manually.

Comment: Perhaps I've misunderstood something, but it feels like you are over-complicating things. As you are using MVVM I assume your listview is bound to a collection of objects (e.g. a "Customer" class). A standard approach would be to add a boolean property to that class (e.g. "IsSelected") and bind the checkbox `IsChecked` to this. When you click save, just iterate through the collection and examine the IsSelected property of each object to determine whether it was checked in the UI.

Comment: I see your point and where you're coming from. However, I'm binding directly to my Entity framework entities (db first) where ever I can. I know a lot of people consider this to be mixing up the VM with the M, but to me it seems like a good way of avoiding having to essentially re-write the entities and do a lot of boiler plate code. There are cases where my VM properties are more complex than just a connection to the M, and I could solve it that way, as in your suggestion, but I want to avoid it if possible.

Comment: What I do here is rather than "duplicate" the entire entity as a model, create a model class that acts as a wrapper around the entity. Expose the entity as a property in its own right (so you can still bind to its properties), then add any other properties to the model as needed by your V/VM, e.g. the `IsSelected` property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I managed to solve this in a way inspired by Andrews suggestion.

I added a wrapper class like this:

```
class MyOccExpLimitComment
{
    private ObservableCollection<OccupationalExposureLimitComment> Occuring;

    public MyOccExpLimitComment(ObservableCollection<OccupationalExposureLimitComment> occuring, OccupationalExposureLimitComment inner)
    {
        Occuring = occuring;
        Inner = inner;
    }

    public OccupationalExposureLimitComment Inner { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get
        {
            return Occuring.Contains(Inner);
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == false)
            {
                if (Occuring.Contains(Inner))
                    Occuring.Remove(Inner);
            }
            else
                if (!Occuring.Contains(Inner))
                    Occuring.Add(Inner);

        }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyOccExpLimitComments}" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="153" Margin="2,2,0,0" Grid.Row="8" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="296">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn Width="269">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" Content="{Binding Inner.Title_SV}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
```

Property:

```
    private ObservableCollection<MyOccExpLimitComment> myOccExpLimitComments;
    public ObservableCollection<MyOccExpLimitComment> MyOccExpLimitComments
    {
        get
        {
            if (myOccExpLimitComments == null)
                myOccExpLimitComments = new ObservableCollection<MyOccExpLimitComment>(AvailableOccExpLimitComments.Select(c => new MyOccExpLimitComment(OccExpLimitComments, c)));
            return myOccExpLimitComments;
        }

    }
```

So every element in my collection is aware of its existence in the collection through the Occuring reference to the collection, and uses the setter to update the collection when the boxes are checked/unchecked.

Comment: This is close, but has the unfortunate side effect of unticked elements no longer appearing in the list, (if correctly updated with events)

Better would be keeping track of 2 collections, one representing the total elements, and one that contains only the selected elements.

This also aids when refreshing the available elements from the database if updates are needed.

Comment: You don't need to check `Contains` when `Remove`ing an element from a list. It will just do nothing if the element doesn't exist.